# File.WriteAllBytes creating 0 byte files

Tags: c#, .net, io

Is it possible for this combination of lines to create a 0 byte file? I would expect the write to always complete.  Thanks!

```
File.WriteAllBytes(file_name, encrypted_data);
encrypted_data = null;
```

Edit: assuming my byte array isn't empty of course, which I am adding checks for.

Comment: If the `encrypted_data` has a positive length, the output file `file_name` cannot be zero length,

Comment: If the code is producing a zero length file, then the likely cause is that the file is already open (in your code or another process), and your code is catching and hiding the exception thrown when `WriteAllBytes` fails.

Comment: Standard mistake is looking at the wrong file, one you created earlier when you were debugging the code.  Standard reason for that is that *file_name* is a relative path so gets created in a pretty random location that depends on the nastiest global variable in programming, Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: That null assignment seems to have nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to user writeByte instead of  File.WriteAllBytes

```
FileStream stream = File.Open(FilePath,FileMode.OpenOrCreate);            
                   if (null != stream)
                   {
                       byte[] encrypted_data=something; // your bytes
                       foreach (byte b in encrypted_data)
                       {
                           stream.WriteByte(b);
                       }
                   }
stream.Close();
```

you can still use System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes when you read file

Comment: Why would this make a difference?